# How to pass props to a children in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass props to a children. Right now one of my components has a state and it's rendering other two components:

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    plantation: {
      points: [],
      finished: false
    },
    cultures: [
      {
        culture: "",
        points: []
      }
    ]
  });

 return (
    <MoveHive>
        <PlantationMap />
    </MoveHive>
  );
```

In `MoveHive` I render the `<PlantationMap>` as a children using `props.children` and it works great.

However I want to pass the `state` from the first component to `<PlantationMap>`. I tried to do like regular props:

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    plantation: {
      points: [],
      finished: false
    },
    cultures: [
      {
        culture: "",
        points: []
      }
    ]
  });

 return (
    <MoveHive>
        <PlantationMap state={state} setState={setState} />
    </MoveHive>
  );
```

But `<PlantationMap>` doesn't receive the props, `const { state, setState } = props;`, both return null.

How should I pass the props in this case?

I'm using Hooks, so no classes, just functions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach (using regular props) is correct.

As you can see from [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mcclintock-6cskt), passing props does indeed work.

Off the top, two things may go wrong in your setup:

1. Your code has not been compiled so you are seeing stale output.
2. MoveHive component calls [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) on children and messes with its props.

Comment: You were right. Actually my approach was working. I was trying to render the `MoveHive` from a test route, without rendering the first component. So the state wasn't declared. My fault